# Having trouble parenting cloth to armature

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, cloth-simulation

I am doing the Clinton Jones (Pwnisher) Alternate Realities challenge, which for me, is my first big project. I am trying to perform the function whereby you parent the clothing item you've made for your character to the armature and do a data transfer from the body mesh to transfer vertex groups to the shirt. So far, I've been unsuccessful and I am unsure if the issue is that my body mesh came with an armature when I imported it in Daz so the name of the vertex groups differs from the base armature that the project file came with that I've retargeted my body mesh to or if it's something else.

All told, the big issue is that the arms are clipping through the sleeves so whether I'm able to solve this through rigging or other means is fine by me, I'm just at a loss for a solution so far. Project file here: https://gofile.io/d/KY3kGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: body and shirt]
[image: animation issues]

You have a cloth simulation with a "runaway" animation. There are several problems with this. Mainly with the modifier stack.

- the *Mirror* modifier on the shirt should be applied and removed from the stack.
- the *Armature* modifier on the shirt has the wrong armature and the modifier should be on top
- the *Data Transfer* modifier should be bound first, then applied and removed from the stack
- the body mesh is rather high-poly (65k vertices) and has a (fortunately deactivated) *Subdivision Surface* modifier on it. The mesh is heavy for animation.

But even if you fix these issues the shirt has still weird deformations when the character is posed. And it gets worse if you run the animation. I afraid the topology of the shirt is not something that is ideal for this.

If this is your first big project it might be easier to make the shirt from the body. I would use a cloth simulation with an animated character only for cloth where it is really needed, like a tie, a skirt, or a dress.

To create a shirt from the body copy the body, add and apply a *Decimate* modifier with 2 un-subdivision iterations. Then add seams where the real-world cloth has seams (top of the shoulder, around the arms at the shoulders, and at the sides). Select the faces (<kbd>L</kbd>, limit to seams), duplicate them, and separate them. Remove the nipples and the belly button and grid fill the holes. Remove some edge loops at the front of the neck (it's not done in the screenshot).

Then go to *Sculpt* mode, and inflate the new shirt a little bit so it doesn't look so skin-tight. With the *MultiRes* modifier and *Cloth* brush you can more details and wrinkles. Bake the normal map from the MultiRes before you render animations. Add a *Soldify* modifier to give it some thickness if you like.

[image: new shirt]

Finally, parent the armature (*With Empty Groups*), and transfer the weights from the body. Check the modifier stack and make sure the *Armature* modifier is on the top of the stack. Then it should deform fine.

Comment: So that worked super well as far as deforming the shirt to work with the body mesh, but the only issue I’m encountering now is that along the seams, there’s these weird distorted textures.

Comment: The issue could be the UV maps. Did you check them in the UV editor? At the borders there can stretching occur. An "Unwrap" operation should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

im doing his challange too, and I have the same problem as you because i have many cloth simulations.
Its the problem with his blend files.
the problem with his files are,
frame 0 is T-pose and frame 1 is the start of the animation, there's no frames in between for smooth transitions.

So I just unlocks every keyframe they lock, (camera and everything)
and moves every keyframe by 50 frame except the T-pose,
so the transition of the T-pose (on frame 0) and the first animation (frame 51) are smooth
so the cloth have time to simulate

[image]

goodluck on your challange